# How do I use IN operator but with AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `Person` and `Interest`

`Person` table structure

```
Id | Name
```

`Interest` table structure

```
Id | Person Id | Interest Category
```

My question is how do I get person who have a liking for the category 'music' AND 'movie' AND 'sport'. The category will be dynamically.

So it will like using IN operator but by using AND condition not OR condition in the IN operator.

```
SELECT `Person Id` FROM Interest
WHERE `Interest Category` IN ('music', 'movie', 'sport');
```

Comment: @zerkms you are absolutely correct, but I'd rather not claim your answer as mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `HAVING COUNT`. The number would have to be dynamically too.

```
SELECT person_id
FROM interest
WHERE interest_category IN ( 'music', 'movie', 'sport');
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` almost always slows down I guess?

Comment: This would have to be tested, but I doubt that there is a faster solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM Person p
JOIN Interest i1 ON p.id = i1.person_id AND i1.interest_category = 'music'
JOIN Interest i2 ON p.id = i2.person_id AND i2.interest_category = 'movie'
JOIN Interest i3 ON p.id = i3.person_id AND i3.interest_category = 'sport'
```

Comment: nice, but the 'interest category' is not only three it can be more than 10. How do I can maintain the performance of my query.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT DECODE(A.RES, B.RES, I.INTEREST_CATEGORY, 'FALSE') AS FINAL_RES
  FROM INTEREST I,
       TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLl('music', 'movie', 'sport')),
       (SELECT LENGTH(WM_CONCAT(COLUMN_VALUE)) AS RES
          FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLl('music', 'movie', 'sport'))) A,
```

```
   (SELECT LENGTH(WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT I.INTEREST_CATEGORY)) AS RES
      FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLl('music', 'movie', 'sport')),
           INTEREST I
     WHERE I.INTEREST_CATEGORY = COLUMN_VALUE) B
```

WHERE I.INTEREST_CATEGORY = COLUMN_VALUE

This query has 2 parts

```
(SELECT LENGTH(WM_CONCAT(COLUMN_VALUE)) AS RES
          FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLl('music', 'movie', 'sport')))
```

This calculates the length of the values provided as input

The 2nd query

```
(SELECT LENGTH(WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT I.INTERESET_CATEGORY)) AS RES
          FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLl('music', 'movie', 'sport')),
               INTEREST I
         WHERE I.INTEREST_CATEGORY = COLUMN_VALUE)
```

calculates the length of the categories matched with the database entries.

Then these 2 lengths are finally compared and the IDs are returned.

This is a real long way to get this done, but in case you do not want to use group by(which is far smaller coding), this may be a method for your query.

Hope it helps

Comment: This only works for Oracle i think. I can't find DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLl function in MySQL, which is the database he was using