# Linq select row on group that contains multi ids

Tags: c#, linq

**Data that my list folds looks like so:**

```
ID  |  Name      | TypeId  | CategoryId  |  
-----------------------------------------
1   |  Rows1     | 10      | 1           |  
2   |  Rosw2     | 20      | 1           |  

3   |  Rosw3     | 30      | 2           |  
4   |  Rosw4     | 20      | 2           |  

5   |  Rosw5     | 10      | 3           |  
6   |  Rosw6     | 10      | 4           |

7   |  Rows7     | 10      | 1           |  
8   |  Rosw8     | 20      | 1           |
```

I would
get only the groups that have TypeID 10 and 20 (logic and condition)
and not those with different elements.

**My theoretical result is**

```
ID  |  Name      | TypeId  | CategoryId  |  
-----------------------------------------
1   |  Rosw1     | 10      | 1           |  
2   |  Rosw2     | 20      | 1           |  
5   |  Rosw5     | 10      | 3           |  
6   |  Rosw6     | 10      | 4           |
7   |  Rows7     | 10      | 1           |  
8   |  Rosw8     | 20      | 1           |
```

In my software items to filter can be even more than two (10,20).
They can be from 1 to n.

my groups are composed of TypeID and CategoryId

I use c# on vs express.

I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: Yeah so some `Where()` and `Contains()` magic will get you a long way. What have you tried?

Comment: But Contains It does not use a logical or?

Comment: `Contains` uses whatever you write into it. If you want an or use `||` same with `Where`. They take an expression for evaluation

Comment: @ Rahul Singh just now TypeId == 10 and TypeId ==20 and TypeId ==30 and TypeId =N... and these must be part of a group

Comment: for me to understand is how to have the clause in sql but with logic and

Comment: like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813088/how-do-i-use-in-operator-but-with-and-condition
but I can have more time for each group 10 or 20

Comment: Why isn't the 4th row included?  It's TypeId is 20.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what you are asking as you talk about grouping but there seems to be no groups in any of the examples, are you actually asking about filtering with a where clause?

Comment: @juharr because in the group is not present on 10

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow You mean because there isn't a row where the Category ID (2) is also present with a Type Id of 10?

Comment: my group is CategoryId and only each group must have both 10 and 20

Comment: What if there is a categoryID that has 3 rows one with a TypeID of 10, one with 20 and a third with 30.  Will you take all 3 rows, only the rows with 10 and 20, or none since there was a row that had a value other than 10 or 20?

Comment: @ juharr only the row 10 and 20

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow: can you edit your question instead of commenting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the foliowing

```
List<int> types = new List<int>{ 10, 20 };
var query = db.Table
    .Where(x => types.Contains(x.TypeId))
    .GroupBy(x =>  x.CategoryId)
    .Where(grp => types.All(t => grp.Any(x => x.TypeId == t)))
    .SelectMany(grp => grp);
```

First this filters out the rows that do not have a `TypeId` of 10 or 20.  Then it groups on the `CategoryId`.  Then it filters out the groups that don't have at least one row with both a `TypeId` of 10 and 20.  Finally it flattens the remain groups out.

I'm not 100% sure that EF or whatever Linq provider you use will like that.  You might have to put an `AsEnumerable()` after the `GroupBy`.

An alternative that doesn't use a `List<int>` and should be compatible with EF would be

```
var query = db.Table
    .Where(x => x.TypeId == 10 || x.TypeId == 20)
    .GroupBy(x =>  x.CategoryId)
    .Where(grp => grp.Any(x => x.TypeId == 10) && grp.Any(x => x.TypeId == 20))
    .SelectMany(grp => grp);
```

Comment: I can not understand this part
     .Where (Grp => types.All (t => grp.Any (x => x.TypeId == t)))

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow That keeps groups when all of the types exist in any of the groups.  Basically the `All` returns `true` if the lambda statement it contains is `true` for all the values in `types`.  Then the `Any` will return `true` if the lambda it contains returns `true` for at least one of the rows in the `grp`.

Comment: Where as I understand it (grp => this takes the lines of each group. types.All cycles all elements types. grp.Any (x => cycles every element of the group and make sure it's the same types

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous types to group by multiple properties/columns:

```
List<int> types = new List<int>{ 10, 20 };
var query = db.Table
    .Where(x => types.Contains(x.TypeId))
    .GroupBy(x =>  new{ x.TypeId, x.CategoryId })
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: This wouldn't return rows 7 and 8, but would return the 4th row.  Based on the comments by the OP I don't believe this is correct.